# Rename/organize images based on EXIF creation date using imagemagick

Tags: image, command-line, imagemagick, exif, exiftool

I'm looking for a command line solution to rename, organize digital photos into directories, using creation date from EXIF info.

`DCIM/**/*.[JPG|CR2]` > `/path/to/gallery/[YYYY-MM-DD]/[YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS-C].[EXT]`

I had a working solution using exiftool/imagemagick but it was lost due HDD crash.

I prefer a cross-platform solution - windows laptop and unix based NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This exiftool command should do what you want (test it out first, of course)
`exiftool -ext jpg -ext cr2 '-filename<CreateDate' -d '/path/to/gallery/%Y-%m-%d/%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%%-c.%%e' /Dir/To/Process`

I'm assuming that you meant cr2, not rc2.
This command is for a linux/mac system, change the single quotes to double quotes for a Windows system.